# Complex conjugate clarification.

Tags: complex-numbers

So I understand that something like $4-i$ is a complex conjugate of $4+i$, however are things like; (a) $-4+i = \overline{-4-i}$, (b) $-4+i = \overline{4+i}$, and (c) $-4-i = \overline{4+i}$.

Generally am I allowed to say an reflection of a complex number about the x, y, or both axis is a conjugate of the original number?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Conjugate of a complex number

#### Geometric definition

In the Argand Plane representation of a complex number $z$, its conjugate $\bar{z}$ is the reflection of $z$ about the x-axis. 
[image: The complex conjugate (taken from Wikipedia)]

#### Algebraic definition

For a complex number $z=x+iy$, the complex conjugate $\bar{z}$ is defined as $\bar{z}=x-iy$.

You should be able to show that both definitions are equivalent, i.e. reflection about x-axis causes sign of $y$ to flip.

#### An alternate definition

The conjugate of a complex number $\bar{z}$ of $z$ has two properties

- $z+\bar{z}\in\mathbb{R}$
- $z.\bar{z}\in\mathbb{R}$

In fact, if $\bar{z}$ is defined to be a number having the above mentioned properties, it can be shown that such a number is unique. You can do it yourself. I'll get you started.

- Take $z=a+ib$
- Let $\bar{z}=x+iy$, where $x$ and $y$ are unknowns
- Using both equations mentioned for conjugates above, solve for $x$ and $y$.

You will get a unique value for $x$ and $y$. So, the formal definition statement could be this:

*Definition:* For a complex number $z$, its conjugate is defined to be the number $\bar{z}$ such that

- $z+\bar{z}\in\mathbb{R}$
- $z.\bar{z}\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

Only (a) $-4+i = \overline{-4-i}$ is correct. Others are not. When we take conjugate we only change the sign of imaginary part. Real part not changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your choices (b) and (c) are incorrect. "overline" stands for the "complex conjugate." So for any real number, complex conjugate is itself.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of reflection, reflection about x(real-axis) is conjugation. So (a) is true, (b) and (c) are false.

Answer (score 0):

For a general case we have:

$$z=a+bi \Rightarrow \overline{z}=a-bi$$

where $a,b \in \Bbb R$.

So just $a)$ is correct.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Conjugate of a complex number of the form $a+ib$ is defined as $a-ib$. Conjugate of a complex number is just the mirror image of that complex number along $x-axis$ or so called real axis.

I think this is sufficieent information.